# Message after a form is validated. With no Frameworks

Tags: javascript

I want to display an alert message after I submit the form.
I already validated the form and that works, but I couldn't launch the message once I submit it.

here's my code.

```html
<form class="formulario" name="form_1" id="form_t" onsubmit=" return validacion()">
  <input class="boton" type="submit" id="submit_1" onclick="inputForm()">
```

```js
function validacion() {
  var n = document.forms["form_1"]["nombre"].value;
  var t = document.forms["form_1"]["telefono"].value;
  var c = document.forms["form_1"]["correo"].value;

  if (n == "") {
    alert("Debe completar el casillero con su nombre");
    return false;
  } else if (t == "") {
    alert("Debe completar el casillero con su telefono");
    return false;
  } else if (c == "") {
    alert("Debe completar el casillero con su correo");
    return false;
  }
}

function inputForm() {
  alert("Gracias");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't return false in `inputForm`?

Comment: Return the message but I want it to be displayed after the form was validated and submitted. In this case, the message is popping up even if the form wasn't filled up.

Comment: I generally would do an AJAX request and based on response output it as header (preplaced and just unhidden when a message reveals for 10-15 seconds). Further more users should aim to not upset the content security policy. Running code in-line can allow XSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to put the desired `alert()` at the end of the validation function, because it is only reached if nothing is empty and no `return: false` is called. Therefor the inline event listener in the input isn't necessary.

```html
<form class="formulario" name="form_1" id="form_t" onsubmit="return validacion()">
  <input class="boton" type="submit" id="submit_1">
```

```js
function validacion() {
  var n = document.forms["form_1"]["nombre"].value;
  var t = document.forms["form_1"]["telefono"].value;
  var c = document.forms["form_1"]["correo"].value;

  if (n == "") {
    alert("Debe completar el casillero con su nombre");
    return false;
  } else if (t == "") {
    alert("Debe completar el casillero con su telefono");
    return false;
  } else if (c == "") {
    alert("Debe completar el casillero con su correo");
    return false;
  }

  alert("Gracias");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maid a small improvements of your code.

```js
    function validacion(){
        var n = document.forms["form_1"]["nombre"].value.trim();
        var t = document.forms["form_1"]["telefono"].value.trim();
        var c = document.forms["form_1"]["correo"].value.trim();
      

        if(n == ""){
            alert("Debe completar el casillero con su nombre");
        }
        else if(t == ""){
            alert("Debe completar el casillero con su telefono");
        }
        else if(c == ""){
            alert("Debe completar el casillero con su correo");
        } else {
            alert("Gracias");
        }  
    }
```

```html
<form class="formulario" name="form_1" id="form_t" onsubmit="validacion()" >
  <input class="boton" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre" >
  <input class="boton" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="telefono" >
  <input class="boton" type="text" id="correo" placeholder="correo" >
  <button type="submit" id="submit_1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And one more link that might help: ["alert(...)" should not be used](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1442)